# Get last 5 data attributes and check if they are identical

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="8">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
```

I need to find out if the last 5 `userid` is identical, which in this case would be not. How could I do that with jQuery/Javascript?

All I know is only how to get first and last:

```
var firstid = parseInt($(".message:first").attr("userid"));
var lastid = parseInt($(".message:last").attr("userid"));
```

but I need the last 5..

Comment: Hello donkiged, didn't you try anything? Can you show us the code that you used to try to achieve your desired solution?

Comment: I edited the question, this is all I have found

Comment: You can use `slice()` off of the result of a jQuery operator to get a subset of elements.  http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: Don’t send the message from the server if the client has already see it, imo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Details are commented in the code below:

```js
const initialUsers = [...document.querySelectorAll("[data-userid]")]; // Elements with data-userid attributes

console.log(initialUsers.length); // initial length

const users = initialUsers.slice(initialUsers.length-5); // Slicing for last 5 elements

console.log(users.length); // checking length

const referenceUserId = users[0].dataset.userid; // taking value of data-userid as reference

const allAreSame = users.every( user => user.dataset.userid === referenceUserId ); // checking if all the 5 elements have same value for data-userid attribute

console.log(allAreSame); // If last 5 are same retuns true otherwise false
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="8">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
```

Comment: I pick this one because you were first and have less points :D thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get a specific range of elements use [`jQuery's slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice). In your case you can just pass a -5 as negative numbers are used as an offset from the end of the selection.

After that just get any of the elements' data attribute's value and match it against all the others in a loop. The first time it doesn't match set a flag. Then test that flag and act accordingly

```js
var allMatch = true;
var elements = jQuery(".message").slice(-5);

//gets the first element's data attribute
var value = elements.data("userid");

elements.each(function(){
  //uses the native dom dataset to get data attribute
  //no need to wrap the element in jQuery first
  if(this.dataset.userid!=value){
    allMatch = false;
    //breaks out of the each() iteration
    return false;
  }
});
console.log(allMatch);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="8">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//get the messages
var $messages = $('.message');
//get the last 5, or all of them if there are less than 5
var $last5 = $messages.slice(Math.max(0, $messages.length - 5));

//true if any of the userids does not match the first one
if ($last5.filter(function(){ return $(this).data('userid') !== $last5.eq(0).data('userid'); }).length > 0) {
  console.log('weee');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="8">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
<div class="message" data-userid="7">tada</div>
```